# Domain Access, Revisioning with Workflow Access together in one project

Tags: domain-access

I have installed drupal6.25, Domain Access, Domain Advance, Revisioning with Work flow and Grant modules. I assign node to the particular domain, but it will show access denied for all domain. If I uninstall the revision and grand modules, the node assign is working fine but the node work flow is not working properly.

Please help me...